# Determining the common limit of $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$.

Tags: analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

> Let $x_1>y_1>0$ and for every $n\ge 1$ let $x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n+y_n}2$ and $y_{n+1}=\frac{2x_ny_n}{x_n+y_n}$. Show that $x_n\gt x_{n+1}\gt y_{n+1}\gt y_n$. Deduce that $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ converge to a common limit. What is that limit?

I have completed the first parts of the question but I'm just having some difficulty determining what the limit is.

Thank you

Comment: Hint: Compute the product $x_ny_n$ for every $n$ in terms of $(x_1,y_1)$.

Comment: Wow thanks, done immediately. Thanks